# Getting error while using useDrag({}) method in react typescript with react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-dnd

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { getEmptyImage } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { useAppState } from '../AppStateContext';
import { DragItem } from '../DragItem';
export const useItemDrag = (item: DragItem) => {
  const { dispatch } = useAppState();
  const [, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    item,
    begin: () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_DRAGGED_ITEM', payload: item }),
    end: () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_DRAGGED_ITEM', payload: undefined }),
        
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    preview(getEmptyImage(), { captureDraggingState: true });
  }, [preview]);
  return { drag };
};
```

[react-dnd issue images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC5DV.png) [with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1r7K.png)

> Geeting this error on useDrag

```
Argument of type '{ item: DragItem; begin: () => any; end: () => any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FactoryOrInstance<DragSourceHookSpec<unknown, unknown, any>>'.
```

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'begin' does not exist in type 'FactoryOrInstance<DragSourceHookSpec<unknown, unknown, any>>'

Answer (score 1):

begin spec is depreciated in react-dnd v14, use item instead and type spec is required in useDrag. [Link here](https://openbase.com/js/react-dnd/versions)

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { getEmptyImage } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { useAppState } from '../AppStateContext';
import { DragItem } from '../DragItem';
export const useItemDrag = (item: DragItem) => {
  const { dispatch } = useAppState();
  const [, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    type: item.type,
    item: () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_DRAGGED_ITEM', payload: item }),
    end: () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_DRAGGED_ITEM', payload: undefined }),
    
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    preview(getEmptyImage(), { captureDraggingState: true });
  }, [preview]);
  return { drag };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above did not work for me, what I did was the following, I returned Item + the dispatch call back. But thank you anyways, your answer pointed me to the right direction.

```
import React from "react";

import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { useAppState } from "./AppContext";
import { DragItem } from "./DragItem";



export const useItemDrag = (item: DragItem) => {
  const { dispatch } = useAppState();

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    type: item.type, //Contains data about the item we're trying to drag
   //Item replaced Begin in the new version of React DnD
    item: () => {
        return [item, 
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_DRAGGED_ITEM",
                payload: item
                }) //Need to return Item + action
        ]
    },

    end : () => 
        
        dispatch({
        type: "SET_DRAGGED_ITEM",
        payload: undefined
        })
    ,
        
    collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
      })
    })
    
    return {drag}
}
```